# writing function to output a histogram of scores

Tags: c, file, structure, histogram

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define FILE_NAME 20
    #define LIST_SIZE 50

    typedef struct
    {
    char *name;
    int score;
    }RECORD;

    float calMean(RECORD list[], int count);
    void sortData(RECORD list[], int count);
    float calMedian(RECORD list[], int size);
    int calMode(RECORD list[], int count);
    int main (void)
{
       // Declarations
         float mean;
         float median;
         int mode;
         FILE *fp;
           char fileName[FILE_NAME];
           RECORD list[LIST_SIZE];
           char buffer[100];
           int count = 0;
           int i;
       // Statements
           printf("Enter the file name: ");
           gets(fileName);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           if(fp == NULL)
           printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
           while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
           {
             if( count >= LIST_SIZE)
             {
                printf("Only the first 50 data will be read!\n");
                 break;
             }
             if( count < LIST_SIZE)
            {
                list[count].name = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
                   sscanf(buffer,"%[^,], %d", list[count].name, &list[count].score);
                  printf("name is %s and score is %d\n", list[count].name, list[count].score);
                  count++;
            }
                for( i =0; i < (LIST_SIZE - count); i++)
            {
                list[count + i].name = 0;
                list[count + i].score = 0;
            }
         }
           printf("Read in %d data records\n", count);
           mean = calMean(list, count);
         sortData(list, count);
         mode = calMode(list, count);
           printf("%2.2f\n", mean);
           fclose(fp);
           return 0;
}

float calMean(RECORD list[], int count)
{
       float tempMean;
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sum += list[i].score;
        tempMean = (float) sum/count;
        return tempMean;
}

void sortData(RECORD list[], int count)
{
    int temp;
    int current;
    int walker;
    float median;
    int size = count;
    for(current = 0; current  < count; current++)
    {
       for( walker = count-1; walker > current; walker--)
          if(list[walker].score < list[walker -1].score)
          {
             temp = list[walker].score;
             list[walker].score = list[walker -1].score;
             list[walker -1].score = temp;
          }
          printf("%d\n", list[current].score);
    }
    median = calMedian(list, size);
    printf("%2.2f\n", median);
    return;
}

float calMedian(RECORD list[], int size)
{
    float tempMedian;
    printf("size is: %d\n", size);
    if ( size % 2 == 0) 
       tempMedian = (float) ((list[size/2].score + list[size/2-1].score)/2.0) ;                   
       else                                                    
         tempMedian = (float) list[size/2 - 1].score; 
return tempMedian;
}

int calMode(RECORD list[], int count)
{
    int tempMode = 1;
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       list[list[i].score].score++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       printf("\n%d:",list[i].score);
       for(j = 0; j < list[i].score; j++)
       {
          printf("*");
       }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return tempMode;
}
```

Hi I'm trying to write a histogram that would list all the score and there frequency of occurences, then use the histogram to find the mode of all the scores, They all in calMode function.

The code above is my attempt of writing this histogram but it is not correct

I got this output:

```
    Enter the file name: in.txt
    name is Ada Lovelace and score is 66
    name is Linus Torvalds and score is 75
    name is Peter Norton and score is 82
    name is Ken Thompson and score is 82
    name is Steve Wozniak and score is 79
    name is Marc Andreessen and score is 60
    name is Donald Knuth and score is 60
    name is Adele Goldberg and score is 71
    name is Grace Hopper and score is 82
    name is Bill Joy and score is 91
    name is Andrew Tanenbaum and score is 71
    name is Brian Kernighan and score is 72
    Read in 12 data records
    60
    60
    66
    71
    71
    72
    75
    79
    82
    82
    82
    91
    size is: 12
    73.50

    60:************************************************************
    60:************************************************************
    66:******************************************************************
    71:***********************************************************************
    71:***********************************************************************
    72:************************************************************************
    75:***************************************************************************
    79:*****************************************************************************
    **
     82:*****************************************************************************
*****
    82:*****************************************************************************
*****
    82:*****************************************************************************
*****
    91:*****************************************************************************
**************

74.25
```

Is there any suggestion for the algorithm of this histogram function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is writing the correct number of asterisks, but the console window you're running this code in isn't wide enough to display that number of asterisks without wrapping. You couldchange the width of the console window. I'm not sure which OS you're running, so I can't guide you through the process of changing the width of your console window.

Changing the scale is an easy alternative, though. Just change your loop so that it ends at the score divided by whatever scale. For example, if you want one asterisk to represent two:

```
   for(j = 0; j < list[i].score / 2; j++)
   {
      putchar('*');
   }
```

Now you have the problem that remainders of two aren't displayed in your histogram. Perhaps you could change the output `':'` scaled to represent two, and `'.'` for any remainders:

```
   for(j = 0; j < list[i].score / 2; j++)
   {
      putchar(':');
   }

   if (list[i].score % 2 == 1) {
      putchar('.');
   }
```

Comment: actually The code was not intended to have many asterisk, for example 60 repeat 2 times so the output should be 60 ** , but in my output it print out each 60 with 60 asterisks on each line